# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\

Tags: python-3.7

I have a list of lists obtained from several text files which were the outputs of a C program.

`r = [['4', '5', '10'], ['11', '12', '13'], ['0', '17', '26'], ['1', '10', ' ....]`

I tried to convert all the str values into int with a simple loop :

```
for i in range(len(r)):
    for j in range(len(r[i])):
        r[i][j] = np.int(r[i][j])
```

This error were raised :

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00

and it converted the beginning of the values into int then there is a sequence of `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\` and the rest of the list did not get converted into int . Does someone know what's happening here ?

Comment: Looks like there are some zero bytes inside one of your strings. Check the input files with a hex editor

Comment: Why `C` tag????

Comment: The text files were obtained from a C program and it's probably why I had this bytes inside my list, I wasn't sure if I should put the C tag or not so I put it sorry if I wasn't appropriate.

Comment: Do you have access to the C sources creating the file?

Comment: If you had and it were about understanding were these 0s came from then this would be another question just tagged C.

Comment: I have the C program but it's kind of big , it's in italian and I don't know C so I don't know where to look. But the text files are created by my python script that runs the C program I don't know if that changes something ?

Comment: Why did you ask this question again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868548/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-x00-x00